SQL formatting in DataGrip
I use DataGrip 2022.2.1. When I use code formatting AND condition in new line set before JOIN
select pfv.value 
from pay.PaymentFields pf
          inner join pay.PaymentFieldValues pfv on pfv.id = _operId
     and pfv.paymentFieldId = pf.id;

I've tried changing the code style in Settings > Code Style >  SQL > General in tab Queries - SELECT Clause but that doesn't work.

This option has not been implemented yet. Formatting JOIN statements by placing AND operator on a new line is currently listed as feature request on our tracker:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-17971/Format-JOIN-condition
